# A short explanation of how MSMQ queue permissions are applied

Tags: permissions, msmq, message-queue

I'm trying to understand how queue permissions are applied in different situations, for example:

- Everyone has Send permission allowed, but "MachineName$" or user doesn't have Send permission allowed
- Everyone has Send permission allowed, but "MachineName$" or user has Send permission denied
- Everyone doesn't have send permission allowed, but "MachineName$" does
- Everyone has send permission denied, but "MachineName$" has it allowed

Surprisingly, I failed to find a short and simple article explaining such things.
And I hate the idea of reading a huge microsoft book to understand a short&simple concept.

So, I will be really thankful for a link to a good explanation and/or an explained answer to my example questions.